# Rake can't be found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

hey i played around with `bundler` and some gems and now i can't use `rake` anymore

if i do a simple db:migrate i get this error:

```
mac:app antpaw$ rake db:migrate
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:282:in `method_missing'
 from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

but rake is listed if i do `gem list`. im using the rails 3.0.0beta4, bundler 1.0.0.beta.5, and ruby 1.9.2dev.

EDIT posted my `export`

```
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ export
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-2GMaKT/Render"
declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
declare -x DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-5RguhF/:0"
declare -x HOME="/Users/antpaw"
declare -x LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="antpaw"
declare -x OLDPWD="/Users/antpaw"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
declare -x PWD="/Volumes/Work HD/localhost/trickpipe"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-N13Ivn/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="272"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/-K/-Kf7svFPHrKmLqMXKAGLuU+++TI/-Tmp-/"
declare -x USER="antpaw"
declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0:0"
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02 revision 28524) [x86_64-darwin10.2.0]
```

Ok i tried it out, look how the error msg is changing:

```
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ export GEM_HOME="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems"
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ rake about
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:282:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ export GEM_PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems"
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ rake about
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:213:in `push_gem_version_on_load_path'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:16:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rake:18:in `<main>'
mac:trickpipe antpaw$
```

now with rvm:

```
mac:trickpipe antpaw$ rake about
(in /Volumes/Work HD/localhost/rails_app)
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:402: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:450: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:958: warning: already initialized constant RUBY_EXT
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:962: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1031: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1240: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1243: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1247: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1251: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1257: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1561: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1567: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1604: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1630: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/antpaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1960: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling a method in Rails::Application is deprecated, please call it directly in your application constant Trickpipe::Application. (called from method_missing at /Users/antpaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bundler/gems/rails-edb5401/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:77)
rake aborted!
stack level too deep

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I've seen something like this with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.  What seems to be happening is that /usr/local/bin/rake is calling some code that ends up trying to link back to a different environment.

Comment: Try removing and reinstalling?

Comment: @ehsanul: sure but it doesn't help

Comment: almost. I think we made some progress, we are now on the line rubygems.rb:779 now and not on rubygems.rb:335 anymore.

Comment: doh im wrong: no i have destroyed all my gem paths :D `gem list` is empty now

Comment: ok fresh update: i installed rvm like you suggested (its indeed very nice) but see my log above. there are still some issues with rake :(

Comment: This started happening for me after i installed the capybara gem (0.4.1.2), which in turn installed/updated a load of other dependencies, rake among them.  I think it's a version of rake that's caused it.

Comment: To give more detail: previously my version of rake was "rake (0.8.7)", after installing capybara (which broke my env), the version of rake was "rake (0.8.7 ruby)".  I'm not sure of the significance of this.  Since i was in an rvm and gemset, i just deleted the gemset, re-made it, took capybara out of my Gemfile, and did bundle install from scratch, and it was fine again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you didn't setup your path environment properly. 
`/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/` is the default package folder of the RUby interpreter shipped with Mac OS X -- crap. When you're saying that you (assume to) use Ruby 1.9.2dev this path is wrong. Please drop `export` in the shell and post the result. Additionally please post you install-/pathes of Ruby 1.9.2dev and your bundled folder.

#### Edit 1:

Okay, quickfix for your issue: `export GEM_HOME="/path/where/your/gems/reside"` and optionally `export GEM_PATH="/path/where/your/gems/reside"` and optionally `export PATH="/path/where/your/gems/reside:$PATH"`. Only in this order! Try one, when it still doesn't work proceed with the next export.

Note that this should fix your problem, but to make a Bundler environment work with rails f.e. you must change your Rails app's config to explicitly use your custom BUndler gem environment. I read some time ago that Rails3 will include options for that; when this is the case (I dunno Rails3) check your those commands.

P.s: Put Bundler aside and use RVM instead. It's much more powerful, more mature and allows for far more flexibility (especially when dealing with multiple interpreters in conjunction with gemsets).

Comment: you don't see it because it's the system wide default

Answer (score 12):

Just an FYI if you used macports to install ruby 1.9.2 I had an issue like so:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
from /opt/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

The fix is to go into /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/specifications and delete "rake.gemspec"

That's it... took forever to find that but, it worked fine

Comment: This same problem happened to me on Windows 7 by the way. The "remove rake.gemspec" solution worked for me in that case as well.

Comment: Worked for me too on Win7. Is this a bug in Rake? If so, has anyone seen a ticket for it? Small problem but it's a ***** to solve. Thanks guys.

Comment: This worked for me too, via Homebrew on MacOS 10.6.5. Of course, doing:

   `rm /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/rake.gemspec`

instead though.

Comment: @mike Same here. It looks like it's a design flaw in the RubyGems app but we 1.9.2 users can't upgrade to 1.4 because the new one will eat our unborn children, steal our credit cards, and kick our dogs... I might be over exaggerating... but only a little.

Comment: Strangely, renaming the file to '_rake.gemspec' didn't work, but renaming it to 'rake.gemspec_' *did*.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with RVM `("warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION")` and so on.

I'm using a Gemset ("rails") to do my dev, but I noticed that my `BUNDLE_PATH` was pointing not to this gemset `(.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails);` instead, it was pointing to the global one `(.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0).`

I fixed the `BUNDLE_PATH` to use the rails Gemset and rake is now correctly worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug in 1.9.2p0
http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/11/ruby-1-9-2-rake-woe/